# Getting stale results in multiprocessing environment

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am using 2 separate processes via multiprocessing in my application. Both have access to a MySQL database via sqlalchemy core (not the ORM). One process reads data from various sources and writes them to the database. The other process just reads the data from the database.

I have a query which gets the latest record from the a table and displays the id. However it always displays the first id which was created when I started the program rather than the latest inserted id (new rows are created every few seconds).

If I use a separate MySQL tool and run the query manually I get correct results, but SQL alchemy is always giving me stale results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can see the changes your writer process is making with another MySQL tool that means your writer process is indeed committing the data (at least, if you are using InnoDB it does).

InnoDB shows you the state of the database as of when you started your transaction.  Whatever other tools you are using probably have an autocommit feature turned on where a new transaction is implicitly started following each query.

To see the changes in SQLAlchemy do as zzzeek suggests and change your monitoring/reader process to begin a new transaction.

One technique I've used to do this myself is to add autocommit=True to the execution_options of my queries, e.g.:

result = conn.execute( select( [table] ).where( table.c.id == 123 ).execution_options( autocommit=True ) )

Answer (score 1):

assuming you're using [innodb](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) the data on your connection will appear "stale" for as long as you keep the current transaction running, or until you commit the other transaction.  In order for one process to see the data from the other process, two things need to happen: 1. the transaction that created the new data needs to be committed and 2. the current transaction, assuming it's read some of that data already, needs to be rolled back or committed and started again.   See [The InnoDB Transaction Model and Locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-transaction-model.html).